How do I parse value from <UserProfile> for following XML data in picture I am new Java I have written this code but not working
Click for XML data to be parsed`
String tagName = "crminfo"; logger.info(xmlResponse); List<Map<String, Object>> parsedXmlData = DataParserUtil.parseXml(xmlResponse, tagName, fieldMapping); logger.info("parsedXmlData: " + parsedXmlData);
public static List<Map<String, Object>> parseXml(String xml, String tagName, FieldMapping fieldMapping) throws Exception {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(xml)) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }

        // Remove BOM if present
        if (xml.startsWith("\uFEFF")) {
            xml = xml.substring(1);
        }
        // Remove ZWNBSP if present
        xml = xml.replaceAll("\uFEFF", "");

        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        List<Map<String, Object>> xmlObjects = new ArrayList<>();

         Map<String, String> fieldMap = fieldMapping.getFieldMap();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element element = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
            Map<String, Object> objectMap = new HashMap<>();

            // Collect all attributes and their values
            NamedNodeMap attributes = element.getAttributes();
            for (int j = 0; j < attributes.getLength(); j++) {
                Node attribute = attributes.item(j);
                String keyName = attribute.getNodeName();
                for (String jsonField : fieldMap.keySet()) {
                    String xmlField = fieldMap.get(jsonField);
                    if (StringUtils.equals(keyName, xmlField)) {
                        keyName = jsonField;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                String value = attribute.getNodeValue();
                ValueConverter converter = fieldMapping.getConverter(keyName);
                objectMap.put(keyName, converter != null ? converter.convert(value) : value);
            }
            xmlObjects.add(objectMap);
        }

        return xmlObjects;
    }

I am expecting the values to be added like
parsedXmlData=[{firstName=Direct_Lens_01, middleInit=,lastName=automation_test, zipCode=, country=CAN, businessUnit=, authorisedRepNo=, city=, afslNo=, companyName=, phone=12345678, }]
but I am getting ParsedXMLData=[{}]
Need Guidance to improve this code and fetch the values
`

Based on your input and output expectations , i tried to code the solution , i am pasting the full solution , try this and tweak it according to your requirements
public class XmlUtil {

public static void main(String[] args) {



    String xmlString = """
            <awd>
                <crminfo>
                    <UserProfile>
                        <FirstName>Direct Lens 01</FirstName>
                        <MiddleInit />
                        <LastName>automation test</LastName>
                        <CompanyName />
                        <Email>di@gmail.com</Email>
                        <Phone>123456789</Phone>
                        <Address1>123 hello st</Address1>
                        <Address2>unit 4439</Address2>
                        <City>Toronto</City>
                        <State>ON</State>
                        <ZipCode>M5H 2R2</ZipCode>
                        <Country>CAN</Country>
                        <Province />
                        <Zip>M5H 2R2</Zip>
                        <ProfessionalDesignation />
                        <Website />
                        <BusinessRegistrationNo />
                        <AfslNo />
                        <AuthorisedRepNo />
                        <Custodian />
                        <TransferAgent />
                        <Address3 />
                        <JobTitle />
                        <BusinessUnit />
                        <FirmType>Academic/Library</FirmType>
                        <JobFunction>Fund Analysis</JobFunction>
                    </UserProfile>
                </crminfo>
            </awd>
                        """;


    List<Map<String, String>> userProfile = parsedXMldata(xmlString, "UserProfile");
    userProfile.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}

public static List<Map<String,String>> parsedXMldata(String xml, String tagName) {

    List<Map<String, String>> result;
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

        DocumentBuilder db = null;

        db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document sourceDoc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xml)));

        sourceDoc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList UserProfile = sourceDoc.getElementsByTagName("UserProfile");

        result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int x = 0, size = UserProfile.getLength(); x < size; x++) {

            //for each user profile print all their nodes

            NodeList profile = UserProfile.item(x).getChildNodes();

            System.out.println();
            Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < profile.getLength(); i++) {
                if (profile.item(i).getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    //System.out.println(profile.item(i).getNodeName() + " : " + profile.item(i).getTextContent());
                    map.put(profile.item(i).getNodeName(), profile.item(i).getTextContent());
                }
            }
            result.add(map);
        }


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException | SAXException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return result;
}
}

